# How to know which constructor was called to create an object instance

Tags: c#

I would like to know if it is possible to know which constructor has been called to create an instance of an object.
For Example:

```
public class Dog
{
    public string Name;
    public int Age;

    public Dog(){}

    public Dog(string n, int age)
    {
        this.Name = n;
        this.Age = age;
    }

    public Dog(string n)
    {
        this.Name = n;
    }    
}
```

Now I create a class instance:

```
var dog = new Dog("pippo", 10);
```

Now (I think with reflection) I want to know from "var dog" which constructor i have used to create a Dog instance if the class has more then one, is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you wan to know that?

Comment: Just set bool value on constructor called

Comment: No, it isn't feasible without recording that information yourself. If you have to know, that's probably a bad sign in itself. (I'd also strongly urge you not to use public fields...)

Comment: Do you think every object should track all events over their entire lifetime just in case someone wants to access some of that information later? (I.e. you want to know which constructor, I want to know if the `Name` property has been accessed, etc). Do you not think that this would have an incredible amount of overhead just on the off-chance that someone wants to obtain that data?

Comment: PLEASE use ctor chaining!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public enum UsedConstructor { Default, Name, NameAndAge };

public class Dog
{
    UsedConstructor UsedConstructor { get; }
    public string Name;
    public int Age;

    public Dog()
    {
        UsedConstructor = UsedConstructor.Default;
    }

    public Dog(string n, int age)
    {
        UsedConstructor = UsedConstructor.NameAndAge;
        this.Name = n;
        this.Age = age;
    }

    public Dog(string n)
    {
        UsedConstructor = UsedConstructor.Name;

        this.Name = n;
    }
```

Comment: Have you ever seen an `UsedConstructor`-enum? No? Neither have I. For one reason: it's a bad idea. No one should need to know what constructor you have used. Instead it might be a good idea to add properties like `IsAgeKnown` or make it a `Nullable<int>` to differentiate between an uninitialized age and an initialized one. If the property is public and has a setter you can also modify them directly without the constructor which makes the enum useless.

Comment: I don't know the use he will give to it. Don't care. This is my implementation for his question. The property is read only as you can see. If the purpose (I don't know) is to know if the age is or not assigned, your solution is the correct.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible and also should be unnecessary to know which constructor was called. If you are in that constructor you know already where you are. If you are in the caling code you also know what constructor you have called.

You could store related informations in a variable. For example:

```
bool dogWithAge = true;
var dog = new Dog("pippo", 10);  
// ....
if(dogWithAge)
{...}
else
{...}
```

If it's so important that you need to know whether the dog was created with an age or not you could also modify the class.

```
public class Dog{

 public string Name { get; set; } // use public properties not fields
 public int Age { get; set; }     // use public properties not fields

 //...
 public bool IsAgeKnown { get; set; }

  public Dog(string n, int age){
    this.IsAgeKnown = true;
    this.Name = n;
    this.Age = age;
 }
}
```

Now you can always check that property: `if(dog.IsAgeKnown) ...`

---

Another approach which works in this case: use a `Nullable<int>` instead of an `int`. Then you can use `if(dog.Age.HasValue)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know that in runtime, you can set a flag in this object. If in debug - set a breakpoint in both constructors.

```
public class Dog{

 public string Name;
 public int Age;
 public string CreatedBy;

 public Dog(){
     this.CreatedBy = "parameterless constructor";
 }

 public Dog(string n, int age){
  this.Name = n;
  this.Age = age;
  this.CreatedBy = "two parameters constructor";
 }

 public Dog(string n){
  this.Name = n;
  this.CreatedBy = "one parameter constructor";
 }    
}
```

You can use enum as well.

Comment: You shouldn't use strings in this way, use enums instead. Its much more efficent, easier to use and read, and makes it harder to mess up.

Comment: You could use float literals, like 40.6 for dog, or 34.7 for cat. They are more compact, yet harder to compare